Spark ml job training XGBoost: stuck at "collect at XGBoost.scala:431"
I am training a xgboost model using spark 3.5.1 ("ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j" % "1.6.2" and "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j-spark" % "1.6.2")
My model config was as follows:
      Map(
        "booster" -> "gbtree",
        "verbosity" -> 1,
        "eta" -> 0.5f,                 
        "gamma" -> 2,                  
        "max_depth" -> 3,              
        "objective" -> "binary:logistic",
        "num_round" -> 30,             
        "subsample" -> 0.8,            
        "colsample_bytree" -> 0.4,     
        "lambda" -> 1.0,               
        "eval_metric" -> "logloss",
        "min_child_weight" -> 1000,    
        "max_delta_step" -> 2,         
        "missing" -> -1,
        "allow_non_zero_for_missing" -> "true",
        "seed" -> 1990,
        "tree_method" -> "hist"        
      )

Unfortunately my job always gets stuck at the task which shows "collect at XGBoost.scala:431".
I tried to look at the source code link but I still could not find a clue. Could anyone who is familiar with this matter shed some light on this?

